# Function to check a point is on a straight line

Tags: python

I have the coordinates of a point *pos = (x, y)*, and I need to check if it is a part of a straight line which passes trought two points *p1 = (x1, y1), p2 = (x2, y2)*.
The formula that i'm using is y - y1 = ((x - x1)/(x2 - x1)) * (y2 - y1), and the code is:

```
        if pos[1] - p1[1] - 10 <= ((pos[0] - p1[0]) / (p2[0] - p1[0])) * (p2[1] - p1[1]) <= pos[1] - p1[1] + 10:
            return True
```

While I was testing it, I noticed that the straight line the slope is the opposite.
[image]

I got this by check every point of the canvas (using tkinter):

```
    p1 = (313, 215)
    p2 = (92, 44)

    for x in range(0, 400):
        for y in range(0, 300):
            if y - p1[1] - 5 <= ((x - p1[0]) / (p2[0] - p1[0])) * (p2[1] - p1[1]) <= y - p1[1] + 5:
                canvas.create_oval(x, y, x, y)
```

The biggest one is the line which is represented by the equation above, the hand drawn one is what I want.

I tried also to test it on geogebra, but there all works properly...what am I missimg?

Comment: Sorry, but the slope depends on the specific parameters you are using, not simply on the formula. In other words: right now we can only guess that either you are misuing the formula, or you forgot to multiply something by `-1` (or similar error) when computing the parameters. We have **no way** to tell you anymore more without seeing the actual data you are using.

Comment: So, if the data continously change, I can't have a general formula to represent a line which passes trough two points?

Comment: What version of Python? `/` might be an issue with Python 2.

Comment: Python 3.6 ....

Comment: No, what I said is that your question is meaningless because we have no way to reproduce your problem. AFAIK your `pos` object could simply contain the wrong data... we have no way to check for this. Provide a **complete** (but minimal) example that we can run to see the results you mention.

Comment: Ok, I added the code I used to draw that image

Comment: The math seems okay. Perhaps you are forgetting the fact that canvas coordinates are not the same as Cartesian coordinates. The origin is upper left corner not lower left, and increasing y moves you down the canvas.

Comment: Assuming you have integer coordinates, you want to avoid using division if possible. Three points `p`, `q`, and `r` are collinear  if `(px - qx)/(py - qy) == (rx - qx)/(ry - qy)`, but the mathematically equivalent test without division is `(px - qx)*(ry - qy) == (rx - qx)*(py - qy)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mathematics seems to be correct with the problem being one of interpretation.

First of all, you could streamline the math a bit:

```
x1,y1 = p1
x2,y2 = p2
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

def f(x): return y1 + m*(x-x1) 

def test(x,y,tol = 10):
    return abs(y-f(x)) <= tol
```

And then just use `test(x,y)` or `test(*pol)`.

The problem is that in canvas coordinates, increasing `y` actually moves you down the canvas. In your sample data -- the line is drawn correctly in the sense that the line segment connecting the canvas points `(313, 215)` and `(92,44)` *is* a decreasing line.

Perhaps you want to plot points as `(x,300-y)` rather than `(x,y)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. compare the slope of any adjacent points are having the same slope. this can be achieved by comparing the slope one every pair of consecutive points
2. if there are three points (x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x3,y3)
3. (y2-y1)*(x3-x2) = (y3-y2)*(x2-x1)
4. continue for all the points until completion

```
class Solution {
    public boolean checkStraightLine(int[][] coordinates) {
        float slope =0;
        if(coordinates.length==1)
            return false;
        else if(coordinates.length==2)
            return true;
            else{
            for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length - 2 ; i++) {

                int y1 = coordinates[i+1][1] -coordinates[i][1];
                int y2 = coordinates[i+2][1] -coordinates[i+1][1];
                int x1 = coordinates[i+1][0] -coordinates[i][0];
                int x2 = coordinates[i+2][0] -coordinates[i+1][0];

                if(y1*x2!=y2*x1){
                    return false;
                }

            }

        }

       return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if y=m*x+n:` where `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the point,  `m` is the slope and `n` is the (coefficient on x? I am not a native English speaker). Calculate the slope with `m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`.

If both points happen to be in the same X coordinate then just check the other is on it too,  but don't check Y.

To know the value of `n` use Gauss'(-Jordan) method/elimination.

Comment: I've already thought at this, but I can't uderstand what is actually "n"...what concretely I have to do?

Comment: Is the point that the line and the Y axis have in common. I searched and looks like is called the Y Intercept.  Is that correct?